# How to create Media entity and attach to user field

Tags: 8, users, media, migrations

I'm trying to import user profile pictures from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. So far I've managed to upload the picture from the url and save it to the file system, create Media entity and use the user id as author. However, the picture doesn't show to the user profile (Manage Form Display), neither to the Edit Media Content Type page.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$values = array(
      'name' => $user["name"],
      'pass' => [
         'value' => $user["pass"],
         'pre_hashed' => TRUE,
      ],
      'status' => $user["status"],
      'mail' => $user["mail"],
      'field_first_name' => $user["field_first_name"],
      'field_last_name' => $user["field_last_name"],
);

$userStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');
$userEntity = $userStorage->create($values);

    $replaced = str_replace("\\", "", $user["picture"]);
    $imageData = file_get_contents($replaced);
    $fileName = basename($replaced);
    $file = file_save_data(
        $imageData, 
        "public://". $fileName, 
        FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_RENAME
    );
    
    $media = Media::create([
        'bundle' => 'image',
        'uid' => $userEntity->id(),
        'langcode' => \Drupal::languageManager()->getDefaultLanguage()->getId(),
        'field_media_file' => [
             'target_id' => $file->id(),
             'alt' => $file->getFilename(),
        ],
        'thumbnail' => [
             'target_id' => $file->id(),
             'alt' => $file->getFilename(),
        ],
    ]);
    
    $media->setName($fileName)->setPublished(TRUE)->save();
   
    $userEntity->field_user_picture->appendItem($media);
```

Is the something missing in the code?

**UPDATE**

I noticed (as also pointed out in the comments) `$userEntity->save();` is missing after `$userEntity->field_user_picture->appendItem($media);`.

However, after I added that line, I get the following error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\media\Entity\Media::getFileUri() in Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem->preSave() (line 321 of /var/www/html/web/core/modules/image/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/ImageItem.php) #0 /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldItemList.php(233): Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem->preSave()
```

Is it related to `file_save_data()` function?

Comment: First, I would be using Migrate for this. Second, I don't see you saving the user object. Is appendItem the proper method to use for adding a field value? If the field doesn't show on Manage Form Display, was it even created correctly?

Comment: @Kevin `appendItem` looks valid, the core `FileUpload` class uses the same method to append a file entity

Comment: Hi! I wrote down some updates on the question. @Kevin was right, `$userEntity->save();` was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. 
I don't need to create a Media entity and append it to the User entity, since the profile picture field type is Image, so I just need to add the `file->id()` to the specific field. 
Here is the code:

```
$replaced = str_replace("\\", "", $user["picture"]);
$imageData = file_get_contents($replaced);
$fileName = basename($replaced);
$file = file_save_data(
      $imageData, 
      "public://". $fileName, 
      FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_RENAME
);

$values = array(
      'name' => $user["name"],
      'pass' => [
         'value' => $user["pass"],
         'pre_hashed' => TRUE,
      ],
      'field_user_picture' => array('target_id' =>$file->id()),
      'status' => $user["status"],
      'mail' => $user["mail"],
      'field_first_name' => $user["field_first_name"],
      'field_last_name' => $user["field_last_name"],
);

$userStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');
$userEntity = $userStorage->create($values);
```

Then, if required, I can create the Media entity as following:

```
$media = Media::create([
          'bundle' => 'image',
          'uid' => $userEntity->id(),
          'langcode' => \Drupal::languageManager()->getDefaultLanguage()->getId(),
          'field_media_image' => [
             'target_id' => $file->id(),
             'alt' => $file->getFilename(),
          ],
          'thumbnail' => [
             'target_id' => $file->id(),
             'alt' => $file->getFilename(),
          ],
]);

$media->setName($fileName)->setPublished(TRUE)->save();
```

Comment: Thanks. This just helped. For some reason, `entity/media` rest endpoint always throws 422. I ended up building my own resource using your code.